# Basic PHP Web Analytics

Tags: php, webserver, analytics

I want to capture as much simple information on a web request with just PHP. What variables are available for me to store? Here's what I have so far:

https://gist.github.com/1363218

My wishlist for this function:

- Turns language into an associative array ordered by weight
- Add full name to language
- Break server software into an associative array
- Get the exact version of the platform, e.g., 'Windows 7 SP1' instead of just 'Windows'
- Classify the request as being from a mobile device, a tablet, or a desktop

Am I missing anything else that could be useful?

Comment: Have you checked this? http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: Also a simple `phpinfo(INFO_VARIABLES)` page will tell you.

Comment: URI, IP, and timestamp are available in the access log. Any reason you want to add yet another layer of logging?

Answer (score 4):

Every information available to you are in variables, so an easy way to find the stuff you want is to have a look at `$GLOBALS`. Create a new PHP file and do `print_r($GLOBALS);`, and you'll see every information your script has gathered.

This includes everything from http headers (charset, encoding, language) to cookies, browser and operating system.

Comment: I'd go with `echo '<pre>'; print_r($GLOBALS); echo '</pre>';` for readability, but yeah, best to start here so +1

Answer (score 1):

Take what you need: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.php

```
PHP_SELF    /blog/article.php
GATEWAY_INTERFACE   CGI/1.1
SERVER_ADDR     Server IP: 217.112.82.20
SERVER_NAME     www.URL.co.uk
SERVER_SOFTWARE     Apache/2.2.15 (Win32) JRun/4.0 PHP/5.2.13
SERVER_PROTOCOL     HTTP/1.0
REQUEST_METHOD  GET / POST / PUT / HEAD
REQUEST_TIME    Request start time: 1280149029
QUERY_STRING    id=10&user=foo
DOCUMENT_ROOT   /path/to/your/server/root/
HTTP_ACCEPT     text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9
HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET     ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING    gzip,deflate
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE    en-gb,en;q=0.5
HTTP_CONNECTION     keep-alive
HTTP_HOST   www.URL.co.uk
HTTP_REFFERER   http://previous.url.com
HTTP_USER_AGENT     Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-GB; rv:1.9.2.6) Gecko/20100625 Firefox/3.6.6 ( .NET CLR 3.5.30729)
HTTPS   1
REMOTE_ADDR     193.60.128.69
REMOTE_HOST     Client server's host name
REMOTE_PORT     5390
SCRIPT_FILENAME     /path/to/this/script.php
SERVER_ADMIN    webmaster@URL.co.uk
SERVER_PORT     80
SERVER_SIGNATURE    Version signature: 5.123
SCRIPT_NAME     /blog/article.php
REQUEST_URI     /blog/article.php
```

Answer (score 0):

$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']. 
This can you about  user's operating system, as well as their browser. 
For example
 Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; PPC Mac OS X; en)